# Sending Login Packet to Minecraft Server in Python Not Working

Tags: python, sockets, protocols, minecraft, struct.pack

I have the following script in Python. What it does is tries to connect to a MineCraft server, first by sending a 'handshake', then sending a login request. The protocol specs can be found here: http://wiki.vg/Protocol

Anyway, the python script works fine, and there are no errors. However, I'm fairly use I encoded the second packet wrong, as when it is sent, nothing appears on the server console. The player isn't connected or anything. It just eventually times out and closes the connection due to the 'client' not logging in in time.

Basically, anyway who has experience with struct.pack() should be able to help me here. I have commented the line where I am unsure of whether I have encoded everything right. The detailed information on packing the data is shown in the link above.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated, I'm pretty clueless with encoding/packing data. :(

```
import struct
import socket
import time
import urllib
import urllib2
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 25566
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

logindata = {'user':'JackBeePee', 'password':'*******', 'version':'12'}
data = urllib.urlencode(logindata)
print('Sending data to login.minecraft.net...')
req = urllib2.Request('https://login.minecraft.net', data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
returndata = response.read() 
returndata = returndata.split(":")
mcsessionid = returndata[3]
del req
del returndata
print("Session ID: " + mcsessionid)
data = {'user':u'JackBeePee','host':u'127.0.0.1','port':25566}


stringfmt = u'%(user)s;%(host)s:%(port)d'
string = stringfmt % data
structfmt = '>bh'
packetbytes = struct.pack(structfmt, 2, len(string))+string.encode('utf-16BE')
s.send(packetbytes)
connhash = s.recv(1024)
print("Connection Hash: " + connhash)
print('Sending data to http://session.minecraft.net/game/joinserver.jsp?user=JackBeePee&sessionId=' + mcsessionid + '&serverId=' + connhash + '...')
req = urllib.urlopen('http://session.minecraft.net/game/joinserver.jsp?user=JackBeePee&sessionId=' + mcsessionid + '&serverId=' + connhash)
returndata = req.read()
if(returndata == 'OK'):
    print('session.minecraft.net says everything is okay, proceeding to send data to server.')
else:
    print('Oops, something went wrong.')

time.sleep(5)

# All above here works perfectly.
enc_user = data['user'].encode('utf-16BE')
#This line is probably where something's going wrong:
packetbytes = struct.pack('>bih', 1, 23, len(data['user'])) + data['user'].encode('utf-16BE') + struct.pack('>hiibBB', 2,0,0,0,0,0)
print(len(packetbytes))
print('Sending ' + packetbytes + ' to server.')
s.send(packetbytes)

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not adding the string or the empty fields;

```
packetbytes = struct.pack('>bihshiibBB', 1, 23, len(data['user']), enc_user, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

About the second `h` in the packing format, a Minecraft string is greater or equal than 2 bytes in length. So I'm assuming that an empty string is just a `short` with the value 0.

**Edit:**
The abovementioned method doesn't work; the `s` needs a length;

```
packfmt = '>bih{}shiibBB'.format(len(enc_user))
packetbytes = struct.pack(packfmt, 1, 23, len(data['user']), enc_user, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working... :/ The Minecraft server just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Hmm, You should at least get a kick packet. Since you seem to be running the server locally, try enabling verbose logging or debug messages from the server.

Comment: I get a kick packet after I 'time out to log in'. I can tell you the data it definitely reaching the server, as I made a script to listen in python and it came up with this (`<<` signifies incoming data, the data is displayed after it): `<< JackBeePee;127.0.0.1:25565
<< 
` (The login data is just like a line break if you try and print it once packed)

Comment: For the record, I'm packing it with this, as you posted: `packetbytes = struct.pack('>bihshiibBB', 1, 23, len(data['user']), enc_user, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`

Comment: The question is, of the server is receiving the data, why doesn't it react? Is there a way to make the server log more?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. :/ You would think it would at least throw an invalid pocket error. I'll look into it.

Comment: I asked around a bit in #mcdevs on FreeNode and it turns out I had the wrong protocol version. I updated it and it's still not working, but something appears on the console: `[INFO] /127.0.0.1:52603 lost connection` That's all.