# Send login packet to Minecraft Server

Tags: authentication, minecraft, python-2.x, python-sockets

Is there a way to send a login packet to Minecraft server from Python?
Here is what I have right now:

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
addr = ("localhost", 25565)
client.connect(addr)
client.sendall(chr(0x02))
client.sendall(chr(0xFD))
client.sendall(chr(0xCD)) # After sending this line server still don't kick me
client.sendall(chr(0x06)+str(117)+str(70)+str(-46)) # And now server kicks me :-(
client.sendall(chr(0x03)+str("Hello World"))
print client.recv(4096)
client.close()
```

I'd like to send login packets with a non-premium username (or one that doesn't exist if it is possible)

Comment: I don't think you can login with non-premium account because the server and the client have to authenticate with minecraft.net. The client has to authenticate twice even.

Comment: How does cracked minecraft work then? You can connect to a cracked server.

Comment: Cracked Minecraft doesn't authenticate, the servers have offline mode on which means that they don't authenticate with minecraft.net. It also means that you can't go on regular servers with a cracked account

Comment: Is it possible to connect to cracked server with python and non-premium accout?

Comment: Probably, though I've never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use someone-else's python library that does it for you - like [quarry](https://github.com/barneygale/quarry) or others mentioned [here](http://wiki.vg/Library_List). Also see this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554622/sending-login-packet-to-minecraft-server-in-python-not-working).